# Why does TypeScript not allow this default generic parameter assignment?

Tags: typescript, generics

I am struggling to understand why the following code

```js
interface A {
    a: number;
}

interface B {
    b: number;
}

class MyMapper<T extends A | B, V extends T extends A ? A : B = T> {}
```

gives me an error:

```
Type 'T' does not satisfy the constraint 'T extends A ? A : B'.
  Type 'A | B' is not assignable to type 'T extends A ? A : B'.
    Type 'A' is not assignable to type 'T extends A ? A : B'
```

This error is caused by the default type parameter assignment for the generic `V` (i.e. the `= T` at the end).

I don't even know what else I could try. Thought maybe this would help somehow, but it doesn't:

```js
class MyMapper<T extends A | B, V extends T extends A ? A : B = T extends A ? T : T> {}
```

I guess it might have to do with this problem: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13995.

---

In case it matters, I am trying implement some kind of a mapper, which:

- can only map either type `A` or type `B`,
- only maps `A => A` and `B => B`.

This is how to use the type:

```js
interface AX extends A {
    x: string;
}

interface AY extends A {
    y: string;
}

let m1: MyMapper<AX, AX>; // ok
let m2: MyMapper<AX, AY>; // ok
let m3: MyMapper<AX, A>;  // ok
let m4: MyMapper<AX, B>;  // error!
```

The default assignment `V = T` would allow me to write:

```js
let m1: MyMapper<AX>;
```

Comment: TS in general can't do much type manipulation on generic conditional types like `T extends A ? A : B`; the type is essentially opaque to the type checker because it doesn't know what `T` is.  I'd say the relevant existing issue is [ms/TS#23132](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23132).  Anyway my general approach when I know `X` is assignable to `Y` but the compiler doesn't is to write `Extract<X, Y>` instead of `X`, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mxD0Bm).  If this fully addresses your question I will write up an answer; otherwise, what am I missing?

Comment: Yes, I think it does, I'll accept the answer if you post it : ]